# azure speech to text api utterance over 15 seconds

Tags: python-3.x, azure, api, speech-to-text

I am trying to work out how to set the Azure speech to text SDK API in python to recognise files over 15 seconds.

I tried this code from python quickstart from here:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/quickstart/python/quickstart.py

```
        speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=cls.speech_key, region=cls.service_region )
        audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=file_name)
        speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
        result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once()

        if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
            response_str = result.text
            # print("Recognized: {}".format(result.text))
        elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
            response_str = result.no_match_details
            print("No speech could be recognized: {}".format(result.no_match_details))
        elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
            cancellation_details = result.cancellation_details
            response_str = cancellation_details.reason
            print("Speech Recognition canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))
            if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
                response_str = cancellation_details.error_details
                print("Error details: {}".format(cancellation_details.error_details))
```

All works, except the fact that only first 15 seconds is recognised. However, this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-to-text
says that if I use SDK api (rather than REST) longer utterances are possible to transcribe.

My questions are:

1. How to set up parameters to accept longer utterances
2. Where can I find detailed info on api settings for python regarding the output type. Ideally if the recogniser returns JSON with recognition confidence, without punctuation.

Any ideas will be appreciated

Comment: Hi,any progress for your issue?Doese my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

> 1.How to set up parameters to accept longer utterances

In fact,you already find the evidence in your question. This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-to-text) already indicates that you need to use Continuous transcription.

[image]

So,the official python sample uses `recognize_once()`,you need to use `start_continuous_recognition()` method to replace it. Please see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-speech/azure.cognitiveservices.speech.recognizer?view=azure-python):

[image]

> 2.Where can I find detailed info on api settings for python regarding the output type. Ideally if the recogniser returns JSON with
>   recognition confidence, without punctuation.

You could view the json structure with the code: `speech_recognizer.recognize_once().json()`

[image]